# Multiple query data in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, aggregate-functions, having

I have a table in a accdb that consists of several columns. They include a social security number, several dates and monetary values. I am trying to query data in here ( there are over 600000 results in the accdb ) .

Social security number can appear once or several times in a database. The dates and the monetary values that are on the same line ( in a different column ) can be different, or not.

So let's say my table looks like this:

```
Ssn      Date1         Date2       moneyvalue   PostDate
123455  12-01-20      03-04-20     5.21        (A datettime value )
```

I am trying to do several things:

First I want to only select the ssn that appear at least twice in the database (or more).

From those results i want to only get the ones where date1 is equal to date2.

From those results i want to get the results where there are different values in moneyvalue per ssn.
I want to compare the moneyvalue from the ssn to the money value from the first time this ssn appears in the database ( so the one with the oldest datetime in postDate) and post this ssn if they moneyvalue is different.

Is this possible? How would i go on about this? I have to do this from within ms access sql window, i can't export the database to mssql as it is protected.

So to sum it up:

I want to retrieve all ssn that appear twice or more in the database, where date1 is equal to date2, and where the monetary value in record x does not match the monetary value in the ssn with the oldest postDate.

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING!

Comment: But start with "where date1 is equal to date2".

Comment: Edit question to show more representative data sample and desired output. What if SSN has 4 records, three of which Date1=Date2 and money is same for two of those - which records should return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question suggests aggegation and multiple `having` clauses:

```
select ssn
from mytable
group by ssn
having 
    count(*) > 1
    and sum(iif(date1 = date2, 1, 0)) > 1
    and count(distinct moneyvalue) > 1
```

Another interpretation is a `where` clause on condition `date1 = date2`:

```
select ssn
from mytable
where date1 = date2
group by ssn
having 
    count(*) > 1
    and count(distinct moneyvalue) > 1
```

However both queries are not equivalent, and my understanding is that the first one is what you asked for.

Comment: Thank you. Solved.